# How can I get a random hexadecimal value like 0xaabbcc in Python that stays as an integer for the sidebar of a Discord bot sending an embed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, hex

I need to get three of them and pick a random one using random.choice

This is what I tried so far and different combinations

```
  option1 = hex(random.getrandbits(24))
  option2 = hex(random.getrandbits(24))
  option3 = hex(random.getrandbits(24))
  answer = random.choice([option1, option2, option3])
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Welcome to the Color Game!',
    description='test', 
    color=answer)
```

The problem is when at the end I say `color=answer`, it doesn't work because `color=` only accepts integers or built in `discord.Colour`s

```
TypeError: Expected discord.Colour, int, or Embed.Empty but received str instead.
```

The integer following the `color=` must be looking like 0xaabbcc. But whenever you use the hex() command it will make it a string

So basically I need a random way of getting these hexadecimal values that stay as integers and not strings. I can clarify anything if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Python `hex` functions returns an hexadecimal string representation on an integer, Python doesn't discriminate between decimal and hex int notation, so just give the color parameter as an integer:

```
  option1 = random.getrandbits(24)
  option2 = random.getrandbits(24)
  option3 = random.getrandbits(24)
  answer = random.choice([option1, option2, option3])
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Welcome to the Color Game!',
    description='test', 
    color=answer)
```

Comment: Hey thank you Liam I didn't know they don't discriminate like that. Thanks for solving my problem!